# How to process input value from HTML form in PHP to insert into MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Consider this HTML fragment (which will run a PHP script as the form action):

```html
<label class="form-label" for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
<input type="date" id="dob" class="field date-field dob-field"
  min="1900-01-01" max="2016-12-31" required>
```

How can I get back the value of this date input in my PHP script to insert it into a MySQL query?

Comment: You can use `NOW()` for mysql or `DateTime` class for PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Where is the name = " " for your input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add '**name**' attribute then use it in php `$_POST`.

```
<input type="date" id="dob" name="exdate" class="field date-field dob-field" min="1900-01-01" max="2016-12-31"  required>
```

In php, you can get this by

```
$exdate=$_POST['exdate'];
```

Then use it in mysq query

```
WHERE columnname='$exdate'
```